# How to make a timer that changes a boolean after a certain time while other code is running in c++?

Tags: c++, timer

How can you make a timer that will change a boolean (or variable) after a certain time (for example 10 seconds) in c++. I need this to make a game stop after, let's say 10 seconds and display something like Game Over while the person is playing the game. If you don't understand what I am looking for or need more information just comment below and I will be sure to add more info. Thanks.

Comment: [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) and [`std::atomic<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) may be a start.

Comment: There is so much to explain with such a seemingly simple question. Please do a search for threading or coroutines, but keep in mind there are a thousand ways to do what you're asking (many are clever hacks that work for your particular case). Threads are EXPENSIVE and have a lot of considerations necessary to be made before you can use them effectively.

Comment: Threads are the easy way, but I'm with Qix here. See if your operating system offers a timer you can register a callback with. When the callback is called, it sets the boolean and you carry on. The boolean needs to be safe from concurrent access. the aforementioned `std::atomic` can help here.